# Can I withdraw EDD funds without the account number?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, california, unemployment

I have money issued from the Employment Development Department (EDD), but I don't have the Bank of America EDD Debit Card yet. Can I use my ID to go into the bank and withdraw money even if I don't have the account number yet?

Answer (score 1):

Bank of America has both digital and physical EDD debit cards. If this is digital then check your email (including spam folder) for the activation link. If physical best to call the bank to ask; usually you activate the physical EDD debit by calling the number in the back and picking a PIN.

Physical is nice if you like using ATMs to get cash, but if you plan to just put it straight into some other account it is easier to go digital.